# Can rsync be used to upgrade operating systems?

Tags: centos, rsync

I have two identical hard disks (say HDD1 and HDD2) with 4TB capacities. I want to create install CentOS, update it, install services and create users on one of the hard disk, say HDD1.

Now if I want to clone this on to  HDD2 it takes a huge amount of time. So instead I would like to first create identical partitions and install CentOS of the same version installed on HDD1 and then rsync HDD1 onto HDD2 while booting from some live OS. Would this serve the same purpose of making a copy (though not a clone) of HDD1 on to HDD2 or would there be some issues that I should be concerned about?

Comment: Can this work? Maybe. Should you do things this way? Heck no. This is precisely what a configuration management system is for.

Comment: As @EEAA says, if you haven't automated the system configuration process, you should start there.  If you have and you still think it's slow, `rsync`ing an entire disk may still take longer than that.  And if you want an identical copy of a disk, using `dd` (you'd need to boot off a 3rd disk because you wouldn't want to read from a mounted filesystem) would make more sense than going through the trouble of installing the OS and then doing an rsync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't quite work. The special directories such as /dev and /proc wont get created properly on the second disk. You also won't get the Master Boot Record from the disk and so HDD2 won't be bootable by default.

If you start by using `dd` to clone the disk, and then make updates to it with `rsync` as more things are installed or updated you might have more luck.

https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/ManualInstall might also give you some pointers on what else might need to be copied over.